# Set Google Chrome default font

Tags: settings, chrome-for-android, fonts

As of this morning, Google Chrome Beta has suddenly begun using a silly font (HYTravel) as the default in web pages. (See screenshot below.) Setting the Android default application font (a feature offered on my LG Viper 4G LTE) is not involved—I’ve set that and unset it, with no effect on Chrome’s behavior.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get rid of this setting?

[image: screenshot of Chrome using silly font]

Comment: It seems to be only affecting LG phones. My Lucid is doing the same thing and there is a conversation [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/-nS44H44Aqs) about it. All LG.

Comment: Looks normal on my Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an LG bug exposed by a recent Google Chrome change: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/-nS44H44Aqs%5B1-25-true%5D